Paraphrasing the response from LLM as per our need
I am trying to understand few things here. Here is my requirement.
I give a prompt and for this prompt the I have an agent that should call 3 plugins. Since there were some inconsistencies in the generated planner, I overridden the planner to call these 3 plugins and return the response.
eg. prompt: get me the employee details whose designation is manager and above and who have not been promoted in the last 3 yrs and the Certifications they have completed.
After the planner was overridden, everything works fine for me and I get the desired response.
Now what I am trying to understand is I cannot expect the user to give such a big prompt every time. the user might give the prompt like get me the employee details.
For this prompt  Get me the employee details, since I have overridden the planner, all three plugins are called. but unfortunately the response paraphrasing happens only as per the give prompt. i.e., even though I get all the details its not getting returned. only the employee details is getting returned.
What I am trying to understand is how can I tell the LLM to paraphrase as per my first prompt even though I give second prompt.
